# Difference between the two Java operators: != vs !equals

Tags: java, operators

Is this code:

```
elem1!=elem2
```

equivalent to this one?

```
!elem1.equals(elem2)
```

It compiles both ways, but I'm still unsure about it...

Comment: what does this have to do with generics?

Comment: I just realized that nothing lol

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't use the == and != operators on anything but primitive types. See Oli's and Matti's answers for an explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`==` (and by extension `!=`) check for object identity, that is, if both of the objects refer to the very same instance. `equals` checks for a higher level concept of identity, usually whether the "values" of the objects are equal. What this means is up to whoever implemented `equals` on that particular object. Therefore they are not the same thing.

A common example where these two are not the same thing are strings, where two different instances might have the same content (the same string of characters), in which case a `==` comparison is false but `equals` returns true.

The default implementation of `equals` (on `Object`) uses `==` inside, so the results will be same for objects that do not override `equals` (excluding nulls, of course)

Answer (score 7):

In general, no they're not the same.  The first version checks whether `elem1` and `elem2` are references to the same object (assuming that they're not primitive types).  The second version calls a type-specific method to check whether two (possibly distinct) ojects are "equal", in some sense (often, this is just a check that all their member fields are identical).

I don't think this has anything to do with generics, as such.